# Power Query / Excel tables: Auto-filling when it should not

Tags: excel, powerquery, autofill, autofilter

I have a Power Query sheet that is sourced from two Excel tables.  The query table is for accounting to keep track of what lab tests have been charged and those pending.  The query and sheets seem to be working fine independently. All of the new charged entered in the two source sheets get pulled over into the query just fine.

Problem:
I added a fourth table with two columns, adjacent to the Query table to use for sorting.  When the accountant has billed the customer, they mark an "x" in the column.  The column is filtered such that any "x" is hidden, since it is complete.  Only unbilled items are seen by accounting.

What is happening is that when a new line is brought over from one of the source sheets, they are automatically filled in with an "X" with some excel autofill function.

[image: Small Snippet of sheet]

Columns A -> O are part of the query
Columns P & Q are the fourth table.

I have disabled Autofill and Auto Complete
[image: File/Options/Advanced/disable autofill]

I have disabled some Autocorrect options
[image: Autocorrect diabled]

When I delete out the inappropriate X's and "Refresh" the data, the "X" from one sheet returns and from one it does not.  I don't know why or how, since the "Line Item Complete" column is NOT part of either source sheet.  It is not part of the query.  I have no idea why the column is auto-filling,, and worse discriminate based off the source sheets that are not linked to those columns.

Please help!

Comment: I don't get exactly what the problem is, but check this post to see if it helps: https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/

Comment: Ricardo & User2895444 - this is exactly correct.

Even though the table "looks" like it is connected it is not.  The indexing is lost or rather, never established, so the new lines "float".

The X"'s only looked like they were re-populating but they were actually simply "Shuffling" around.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is actually that new data is appearing in rows that already have an x typed in them, not that something is being autofilled. The x is associated with the location it's typed in, not the data in the other cells.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that I needed to make a self-referencing table.  As per Ricardo mentioned above, the issue was the loss of indexing between the query and the new columns I added later.

The sheet looked like it was being auto filled because:

1. there merge combined two sheets from two plants that kept adding new data,
2. there was sufficient data that the shuffling / filtering of the rows made it look as though the column was auto filling, when in fact, it was just "shuffling data".
3. When I deleted the unexpected autofill, the next time the data was refreshed, the rows just "indexed" into the now deleted cell, looking like an autofill.

to solve the problem I used Ricardo's link:
https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/
and "Doug's" video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHgv_gWw7iQ

Thanks -